# Record Audio and upload file to firebase storage Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, voice-recording

I am using the [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) package to record and play audio. On Flutter Web, on stopping the recording the recorder returns a path/URL of this type: `blob:http://localhost:63986/b60f31ce-b94d-48c8-8a4a-2d939effe6d8`

I want to upload the audio recording to Firebase Storage but dart.io can't be used for flutter-web so can't use the File method. Even after searching, I didn't find a way to achieve it. I don't know how to proceed. How can I write the audio to file and upload it to firebase?

My Code:

```
  import 'dart:html' as html;
  import 'dart:io' as io;

  final recorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();
  final player = FlutterSoundPlayer();
  String fileName;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initRecorder();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    recorder.closeRecorder();
    player.closePlayer();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> initRecorder() async {
    if (!kIsWeb) {
      final status = await Permission.microphone.request();
      if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('Grant Permission form mic first!')),
        );
      }
    }
    await recorder.openRecorder();
    await player.openPlayer();
    recorder.setSubscriptionDuration(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
  }

  Future<void> record() async {
    fileName = DateTime.now().toString();
    await recorder.startRecorder(toFile: fileName);
  }

  Future<void> stop() async {
    path = await recorder.stopRecorder();
    if (kIsWeb) {
      if (path == null) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('Grant Permission for mic first!')),
        );
      } else {
        // Get File from path and upload it to Firebase

        print(path);
        // not working for Web
        // final audioFile = io.File(path);

        // html.File() doesn't take path/Url as parameter but
        // File(List<Object> fileBits, String fileName,[Map? options])

        /*
        await FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child('users/uploads/$fileName.mp3')
            .putData(file!.bytes!);*/
      }
    } else if (!kIsWeb) {
      if (path == null) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(content: Text('Grant Permission for mic first!')),
        );
      } else {
        //final audioFile = io.File(path);
        // await FirebaseStorage.instance
        //     .ref()
        //     .child('users/uploads/$fileName.mp3')
        //     .putFile(audioFile);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

I've been working on this for days, and I *finally* figured it out!

When you call `startRecorder(toFile: audioLocation)`, `audioLocation` will be the location of the file after you call `stopRecorder()`, stored in `html.window.sessionStorage` (`html` as in `import 'dart:html' as html;`).

So you need to add `import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;`, create a `fileName` (whatever you want the file to be called in Firebase Storage), and then insert the following piece of code.

```
var ref = await storage.ref().child('path/to/file/$fileName');
Uri blobUri = Uri.parse(html.window.sessionStorage[audioFile]!);
http.Response response = await http.get(blobUri);
await ref.putData(response.bodyBytes, SettableMetadata(contentType: 'video/mp4'));
```

This might not be the best way, but it is the way I finally got it to work! Good luck!!

Comment: thanks for your answer friend, I have a question? how do you create the file in web flutter?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. This information in the question should show you how to actually create the file, and then my answer shows how to upload it. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Sumit_VE if my answer helped you, please mark it as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
http.Response response = await http.get(
    'blob:http://localhost:63986/b60f31ce-b94d-48c8-8a4a-2d939effe6d8',
);   

response.bodyBytes //data in bytes
```

Note: Verified in local machine & firebase hosting.